# Why does this case statement only evaluate the else clause?

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, if-statement

Using Rails 3, but I guess doesn't matter. I put this in the template helper.

It always goes to the last case `badge-warning` when I for whatever value I put for `rating`, such as `rating_badge(4)`:

```
  def rating_badge(rating)
    case rating
    when rating > 3
      'badge-success'
    when rating < 3
      'badge-important'
    else
      'badge-warning'
    end
  end
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Please improve your question by posting all **relevant** error messages exactly as they appear, and whatever samples you're testing against.

Comment: There's no error message. Rating is an integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a stray *rating* variable at the top of your case statement. The correct syntax is:

```
case
when rating > 3
  'badge-success'
when rating < 3
  'badge-important'
else
  'badge-warning'
end
```

This works for me at the REPL using pry and irb.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the syntax for `case`, I think you must include the word `then`...

```
when something then result1
when something_else then result2
...
```

But you can achieve the same result using `if`:

```
def rating_badge(rating)
  if rating > 3
   'badge-success'
  elsif rating < 3
    'badge-important'
  else
    'badge-warning'
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, I could achieve with if-else, but would like to learn what was wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply a variable to `case`, it will try and match the variable's value against each value supplied to `when` statements. As you put a condition after each `when`, it will first evaluate the condition and then match it against `rating`.
However, the evaluation will ONLY produce `true` or `false` and as apparently you provide a numerical value to `case`, it will ALWAYS fall to `else` case (as `rating` is never `true` nor `false`).

The correct syntax has already been posted by @CodeGnome, but I think you should know the reasons to this failure!

:)